# Do Asians generally want a tourist/visitor to "act Asian", or "be different"?

Tags: japan, south-korea, asia

One of my biggest fears with going to Japan (or Korea, etc.) is that I will offend them somehow by accident.

If I do some silly attempt at holding my hands together to express "thank you", will they think I'm mocking them? Should I not speak any word in their language, not even "thank you", to not appear like I'm "trying to be them"?

I would feel far more comfortable speaking entirely in English and using gestures no different from how I would do here.

I truly cannot tell whether they find it flattering when you "at least try, comical as it looks and sounds", or if they are far more interested in seeing how I speak and act naturally, perhaps even considered "exotic" and "cool" to them.

Does this vary significantly between various Asian nations?

Comment: In urban China at least people may find you "funny" or even "stupid" but probably will not *offended* in basically everything you do that is not clearly provocative. A wide liberty is given to "obvious" foreign tourists (i.e. if you clearly don't look Asian at all).

Comment: I hope you are aware that gestures are culture dependent, and that what is OK in one culture can be offensive in another culture.  A classic being the "OK" gesture itself.

Comment: Do you look Asian or will you stand out as a tourist whatever you do?

Comment: I'm Aryan/White.

Comment: @Keb - so kind-of [Indo-Iranian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryan) then?

Comment: @Keb that's confusing, usually Indo-Iranians self-identify as (South) Asians... But you clearly would not be confused with Japanese, for sure.

Comment: As long as you are not intentionally offensive  you will be fine. I've been in Japan, Korea, Thailand, China, Myanmar, Indonesia, Vietnam, etc. and NEVER had an issue with that. Of course you may do something "wrong" but almost takes it as an honest mistake and it's way more funny and entertaining than offensive.

Answer (score 9):

**You're overthinking this.** Do what's polite back home, and nobody will be offended, because people understand that you're a foreigner and not familiar with local customs.

"Asia" is also way too large a place to generalize about.  If you're visiting a specific country, read up about its customs, and you'll learn about things you shouldn't do there (tramping all over tatami mats in your shoes in Japan etc).